# Search for a file's name through Query Interface in Typo3 without raw query

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

hope someone can help me out here: I am trying to create a query which searches for a file's name and meta data. what I am doing is

```
$constraints[] = $query->like(
            $property
            '%' . strtolower($term) . '%',
            false);
```

and In the `$property` I am using `files.name` and `files.properties` but it gives me an error saying column is not mapped. I get the result when I use `files.title` as it is being referenced in the `sys_file_reference` table, but I checked that the name is saved in the `sys_file` table. So how can I create that mapping, or how do I search for this additional info in the query without using raw query.

Comment: In which repository object you are trying to do query?

Comment: in my custom repository for my model. I get this error `The ColumnMap for property "properties" of class "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference" is missing`

Comment: how you created the query object?

Comment: by using `$this->createQuery()` and then using `$query->like(
                'files.properties.name',
                '%' . strtolower($term) . '%',
                false);`

Comment: does the 'files' property is your custom table property?